# Reading external source of data in Highchart 3D bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

This is the code of 3D bar chart where the data is loaded manually but I want to import data from external source.Can you help me in this code. I have also posted the jsfiddle link of this chart below the code.Thanks!

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        margin: 75,
        options3d: {
            enabled: true,
            alpha: 35,
            beta: 15,
            depth: 110
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            depth: 40,
            stacking: true,
            grouping: false,
            groupZPadding: 10,
            dataLabels:{enabled:true}
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4],
        stack: 0
    }, {
        data: [5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2],
        stack: 1
    }, {
        data: [7, 9, 8, 7, 5, 8],
        stack: 2
    }]
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4dccq/481/

Comment: The following page on Highcharts' website might be helpful for you: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-intro. If you have an idea of what kind of data you're looking to add to this chart, that would be helpful if this document is unclear.

Comment: In addition to Mike's comment, here you can find simple example of adding data from external source. http://jsfiddle.net/YWVHx/637/